# Webmin: write "short" records to zone file?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, fqdn

I'm using webmin to manage BIND DNS zones which until now have been managed manually.

When I add a new record in webmin (A or CNAME) it's writing the FQDN (host + zone) into the zone file. While this is not breaking anything, it's adding a lot of unnecessary text to the already huge zone file.

Example:

```
# /var/named/master/some.zone.com
# manually-added record
somehost01                    IN    A    10.10.10.1
# added via webmin
somehost02.some.zone.com.     IN    A    10.10.10.2
```

Is there a way to configure webmin to not write the FQDN when a record is added to a master zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the "Convert record names to canonical form?" option in the "Module Config" section of the BIND DNS Server module. Setting it to "no" yields the desired result.